# Using system configuration framework to configure IPv6 addresses in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, networking, ipv6

I was going through the System configuration programming guidelines in order to be able to use the framework to programmatically configure IPv6 address on Tunnel interfaces in OS X. However, seems like the guide is a bit outdated since it only refers to IPv4 semantics. I am guessing V6 address configurations should be similar, but wanted to post this question to see if anyone can help with a few code snippets.

The system configuration programming guide I am following is here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_UnderstandSchema/SC_UnderstandSchema.html

The tunnel interface that I using on OS X (10.9.5) is tunnel/tap kernel extension:
http://tuntaposx.sourceforge.net/

Thanks for all the help.